# Docker compose a Server API and Nuxt Client?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, nuxt.js, strapi

I'm trying since 2 weeks to make a docker compose that link an api server (strapi) and a Nuxt app (client)

Nuxt make request to the api server to get data. But I don't know how to make them communicate to share data and make request.

I tried a lot of config but don't work.

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.9"
services:

  client:
    image: nuxt-client
    networks:
      - my-network
    environment:
      STRAPI_URL: server:4040
    depends_on:
      - server

  server: 
    image: strapi-server
    networks:
      - my-network
    volumes:
      - ./data:/app/.tmp/

networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge
```

I try my nuxt app to make a request on the server with the port 4040

In environment, nuxt app take STRAPI_URL which is the url of the api (example: `http://localhost:4040`)

But the request on the network tab is 404

I want to put this docker compose in my nginx proxy manager, and i don't want to make port outside containers.

Any help ? :)

Comment: Your browser application actually runs in your desktop browser, which is outside of Docker.  You must publish `ports:` for the backend application, or a reverse proxy that will forward to it, so the non-Docker browser application can call into the container backend.

Comment: I'm ok with that but nginx proxy manager use his own method with container name to link with the container